# "With each coming day I'm more and more convinced", does this sound idiomatic?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I am trying to translate a sentence from my native language into English. This is my best attempt:

> With each coming day I'm more and more convinced that everything is
> better with you.

What I am not sure of is whether saying "with each coming day" and "I'm more and more convinced" together sounds natural.
I looked online but I could only find the construction "every day I'm more convinced" which does not seem to have the same connotation as the original sentence.

**Context:**
The sentence is part of a post on Facebook written by someone in honor of their wedding anniversary.

Comment: 'With each coming day I'm more and more convinced' is OK grammar, but moving (and altering) 'coming' to later in the sentence like thus: 'With each day I am (becoming) more and more convinced' is better. This form explains a future trend. The form 'every day I'm more convinced' explains a current or past trend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would make more sense if you drop "coming", because that usually refers to future days, and the statement is about the writer's experience of the past. Apart from that,
*With each day I am more and more convinced...*
is understandable. You could also drop the word *with* at the start of the sentence.
I think the other form you mention, "every day I am more convinced" is more idiomatic.